# Current time Minus 4hours

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
new Date(new Date().setHours(new Date().getHours() - 4))
```

This returns me date and time of 1970 . What I want to do is say today's date is 8/19/2013 and time is 5 AM so I want to get date as it is which will be 8/19/2013 but i want to time to be 1AM instead of 5AM.Any help will be appreciated

Comment: works for me: http://jsfiddle.net/KxHLk/ What browser are you using?

Comment: I have check your code and its work fine as you want minus 4 hours

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's unsafe to do it like this, what about 03:00 am? it will return -1.

Do it with `date.getTime()` :

```
var d=new Date();
var time=d.getTime();
console.log(d);
time = time - 4*1000*60*60;
d=new Date(time);
console.log(d);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/G47Fh/1/

Comment: Well i am Plotting it on highcharts graph and when i give this input,Point get plotted on date 1970

Comment: @user2137186 maybe you are plotting it wrong... check out console log with this new code.

Comment: well i was using this "new Date().getTime()" its plot on right date and time but i want time of 4 hours ago so i guess your function is not formatted as new Date().getTime(). Can this be problem?

Comment: `new Date().getTime()` will instanciate an object with current time. please post your code using the date objects

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
var date1 = new Date();
var date2 = new Date();

date2.setHours(date1.getHours() - 4);
console.log(date1);
console.log(date2);
```

JS Fiddle Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/satpalsingh/7pypu/

For more info visit: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_date.asp

Comment: Well i am Plotting it on highcharts graph and when i give this input,Point gets plotted on date 1970

Answer (score 1):

I'd simply subtract 4-hours-worth of milliseconds from the current time:

```
var oneHour = 1000 * 60 * 60;
var fourHoursAgo = new Date( Date.now() - ( oneHour * 4 ) );
```

or

```
var oneHour = 1000 * 60 * 60;
var fourHoursAgo = new Date( ( new Date().getTime() ) - ( oneHour * 4 ) );
```

Comment: Well i am Plotting it on highcharts graph and when i give this input,Point gets plotted on date 1970

Comment: Hmmm, that would seem to imply that the value you are passing in is 0, can you confirm if that is the case? Also, "Date.now()" will only work in newer browsers, you'll need to use "new Date().getTime()" in IE <= 8

Comment: Actually, maybe try passing in the value in milliseconds (i.e. "(new Date().getTime()) - ( oneHour * 4 )" ), I have a feeling that is what hicharts takes